# Process.StartInfo run resource file

Tags: c#, process.start

I am trying use Process.StartInfo() to launch (with elevated privileges) an exe file I built.
I tried the following: 
1. Add the .exe file as embedded resource. 
2. Use the embedded file as follows:

```
Assembly _assembly;
Stream _fileStream;
_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
_fileStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("projectNamespace.filename.exe")
```

3.Build a new file from the _filestream, and run it.

But i'm not allowed to create an instance of the static File type.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post the code for #3.  Also, do you need to embed the EXE?  Can you just have it in the same folder and run it that way?  Seems a bit easier.

Comment: File f = new File(_filestream); I wanted to embed it in order to make the deploying less messy. didn't want people to accidentally delete file etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the file you want to run to the project. Right click the file and set "Build Action" to "Content" in the solution explorer.